# Why does "aseh doche lo saaseh"?

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

There is a *halachic* principle that עשה דוחה לא תעשה - when a positive and negative *mitzvah* conflict, we obey the positive one. The Talmud learns this out of *pesukim*, but what is the *hashkafic*/philosophical reason for this?

Comment: Can anybody give an example where a + and a - mitzvah conflict?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ramban (*Sh'mos* 20:8) says that because positive mitzvos stem from loving HASHEM while negative mitzvos stem from fear of HASHEM and love is greater than fear.

Comment: It's from the רמב"ן על התורה (*Sh'mos* 20:8): ואמת הוא ג"כ כי מדת זכור רמזו במצות עשה, והוא היוצא ממדת האהבה והוא למדת הרחמים, כי העושה מצות אדוניו אהוב לו ואדוניו מרחם עליו, ומדת שמור במצות לא תעשה, והוא למדת הדין ויוצא ממדת היראה, כי הנשמר מעשות דבר הרע בעיני אדוניו ירא אותו, ולכן מצות עשה גדולה ממצות לא תעשה, כמו שהאהבה גדולה מהיראה, כי המקיים ועושה בגופו ובממונו רצון אדוניו הוא גדול מהנשמר מעשות הרע בעיניו, ולכך אמרו דאתי עשה ודחי לא תעשה.

Comment: So one can, for example, carry their kiddush cup and wine across the public domain to their friends home where they have been invited (the friend has no cup or wine) on Shabbat, in order to make kiddush? Positive mitzvah to make kiddush and negative mitzvah (prohibition) to carry in public domain. Good to know...

Comment: @YaacovDeane The prinicple of aseh Docheh Lo Taseh wouldnt apply in your case for 3 reasons. 1 Shabbos is aseh and lo taseh. So can't overide both. 2 Aseh can't be Docheh Lo taseh which has kares. 3 Aseh Docheh Lo taseh has to be at the same time. You're doing the Lo taseh at the same time you're doing the Aseh.

Comment: @user4784 My reason for my ridiculous comment was to point out, that so as not to mislead the general public, the presumption of the question from the OP needs to be edited.

Answer (score 10):

R' Nissim Gaon on Shabbos 132b says the following:

> ובזה הפירוש שפירשנו יסיר מלבך ספק גדול שמסתפקין בו בני אדם ושואלין עליו והוא שאומרין מאחר שאנו יודעין שאזהרת לאו קשה מציווי עשה היאך יבא עשה וידחה האזהרה של לאו שהיא חמורה ממנו ומדרך הידוע שהחמור דוחה הקל ולא עוד אלא שפעמים שעולה על דעתן שיש בענין הזה ענין חזרה בדבר הראשון. והתשובה הוא מה שהקדמנו שהאזהרה של לאו כך נאמרה מיוחדת **וכי הציווי של עשה תנאי הוא בה** וכן אמרו רז"ל (ספרי פ' תצא) מחלליה מות יומת וביום השבת שני כבשים בני שנה שניהן בדיבור אחד נאמרו ערות אשת אחיך ויבמה יבוא עליה שניהן בדיבור אחד נאמרו מה שאי אפשר לבשר ודם לומר שנא' אחת דיבר אלהים שתים זו שמענו. הבן דבר זה ושמור אותו כי הוא ספק גדול והרי גלינו אותו

Translation (mine):

> ...And with this explanation that we have explained a great doubt has been removed from you heart, which what people have asked, being that we know that the warning from a prohibition is more stringent than the commandment to do, how is it that the commandment comes and pushes off the prohibition which is more stringent than it? As is know, normally the stringent pushes off the lenient. Even more than this, that it may occur to you that there is a retraction of the original statement in this. The answer is as e said, that the prohibition was specified as such, and **the commandment is a condition in it**, as Chazal said, "those who desecrate is (shabbos) shall die" and "on shabbos day, two sheep (are to be offered" were said with one statement, "do not reveal the nakedness of your brother's wife" and "the *yavam* should come unto her" were said in one statement, that which the ear cannot hear and the mouth cannot speak. Understand this, as it is a great doubt and we have revealed it.

Likewise, Rashi on Berachos 20a sv "shev v'al ta'asheh" says the following:

> וטומאת גופי' שהותרה לכהן ולנזיר ליטמא למת מצוה דקא מעקר בידים מפני כבוד הבריות דלאו שב ואל תעשה הוא היינו טעמא דלא גמרינן מיניה דהתם לאו כבוד הבריות הוא דדחי לא תעשה דידה **דמעיקרא כשנכתב ל"ת דטומאה לא על מת מצוה נכתב כשם שלא נכתב על הקרובים**

Translation (mine):

> *Tumah* itself, which is permitted to a *kohen* and *nazir* in the case of a *mes mitzva* even though it he is uprooting (the prohibition) actively because of the dignity of Man despite the fact that (he is not violating passively), we do not extrapolate from there to elsewhere (that one can violate prohibitions for the dignity of Man), because there the reason is not because of the dignity of Man but  because the **prohibition originally was never said on such a case of a *mes mitzva*, just as it was never said on the *tumah* of relatives.**

Comment: Note that a similar logic is used to explain how a Prophet is able to temporarily uproot commandments in the Torah.

Comment: What is the source for this? I have heard it mentioned bit never seen it inside.

Comment: The Rogatchover Gaon quoted [here](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=r54bbqIYAZgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA223#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

I heard today in the name of *Meshech Chochma* (but I have no precise citation) as follows:

When one has these two choices —

- fulfilling the thou-shalt, which forces him to violate the shalt-not, and
- obeying the shalt-not, which forces him to ignore the thou-shalt

— one is *forced* to violate a command. In a case of coercion, one is absolved from guilt; however, in case one is coerced to refrain from doing a thou-shalt *miztva*, one **does not** get reward for having done it. So consider the cost-benefit analysis:

- Fulfilling the thou-shalt, which forces him to violate the shalt-not, means he gets reward for fulfilling the thou-shalt; violating the shalt-not incurs no penalty because it was under duress.
- Obeying the shalt-not, which forces him to ignore the thou-shalt, likewise gets him no penalty; but also no reward for having done a thou-shalt.

So the former option is preferable.

Comment: מאי ולחושבי שמו אמר רב אשי חשב אדם לעשות מצוה ונאנס ולא עשאה מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו עשאה

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=6&format=text

Comment: @ShmuelBrin nice, but (1) your question is on the _Meshech Chochma_: I'm just the reporter. And (2) I believe it says elsewhere אנס ר׳ פטריה ולאו כמאן דעבד דמי.

Comment: http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=869&cat=5&haoro=0

Answer (score 1):

[R. Elazar Azikri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_ben_Moshe_Azikri) states (Sefer Chareidim [Introduction](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45039&st=&pgnum=16)) that not fulfilling a positive commandment is more serious then violating a negative commandment. His proof is that a positive commandment overrides a negative commandment (עשה דוחה לא תעשה), so it is clearly more serious.

> והראיה העצומה שאם לא היה עוון ביטול מצות עשה חמור מן דין עונש לא תעשה
>   למה אתי עשה ודחי את לא תעשה וכי דבר שאין עונש בביטול עשיתו יהיה חמור
>   לדחות דבר שיש בו עונש בעשיתו אלא על כרחך אין הדבר כן

Comment: This looks to me like the Ramban mentioned above repeated by the Sefer Chareidim who lived 3 centuries later

Comment: @user15464 The Sefer Chareidim's explanation has nothing to do with ahavah vs yirah.

Comment: tachlis asei is greater than lo saase this is what the ramban said לכן מצות עשה גדולה ממצות לא תעשה ramban explained why sefer Chareidim left out the explanation