# PTIJ: What was Moshe Rabbenu's favorite college sports team?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Okay it's March Madness, so here goes:

In Deut. 8:12, Moshe Rabbenu tells the Jews:

> פֶּן-תֹּאכַל, וְשָׂבָעְתָּ
>
> *Consume Penn, and you shall be satisfied*.

Clearly they weren't rooting for the University of Pennsylvania; so which college team *did* they like?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Unless it's a cheer: "Penn! Consume and you shall be satisfied!"

Comment: @JoelK  The trop would indicate the first two words go together. But this brings to mind "Let's Eat Grandma!" vs. "Let's Eat, Grandma!"

Comment: ודוק (........)

Comment: @Shalom Trop saves lives

Comment: Seemingly, one should not root for the [sinners in Pennsylvania, Alabama, or Alaska](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100816/)

Answer (score 6):

As would be expected for March Madness, it is inappropriate to choose a particular team, rather, we must eliminate all of the teams until only one is left, and then we will know which Moshe cheered for.  Therefore, I will begin:

Onkelos writes ([Bamidbar 14:16](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Targum_Onkelos/Bemidbar/14.16#m7e2n6)):

> מִדְּלֵית יוּכְלָא קֳדָם יְיָ
>
> There is no UCLA in front of G-d.

Which means that UCLA was also off limits, as Hashem didn't have them in his bracket...